# Как очистить пробелы в строках?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEST1': [1234, None, '  5555 ', '6666 ', datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 12)], 'TEST2': ['7777', '1111  ', '  8888 ', '9999','111111', '0000']})
```

Нужно очистить пробелы по краям у строковых значений.

Пробовал так:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

, но значения с датами превращаются в `NaN`

Comment: В ваших реальных данных на самом деле намешаны целые, строки, и два разных вида datetime??

Comment: В реальных данных во фрейме у меня могут быть типы: строка, int, float, timestamp, None

Comment: С такими данными очень неудобно работать. Непонятно почему смешаны timestamp со строками и числами. Как вы получаете эти данные и что вы хотите с ними сделать?

Comment: Считываю с разных файлов формирую общий frame(иногда попадают такие значения), после фильтрую/обратываю и складываю в csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```